# Why is it slow to update a class property compared to a local on in Swift?

Tags: performance, swift

Consider the following `UIViewController` implementation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var foo:String[] = ["A","b","c"];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for (var i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
            foo += "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

This loop takes around 34 seconds to complete, consumes 100% CPU and uses up 54MB RAM.

If I move the foo declaration into `viewDidLoad` we get near instant results.

My question: What is causing this?

Comment: Is this a Debug build? Have you tried a Release build?

Comment: Stack vs. Heap memory usage?

Comment: This is no more a problem now, on swift 4 this takes only 0.0072 seconds

Comment: Why it takes 100% cpu is because it's on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

In the Playground I've tried the following:

- Changed Environment to iOS
- Built one function that just calls super.viewDidLoad() and another which does the additional array concatenation

It takes approx. **7secs** for just calling the super-method and additional 3secs (**10secs**) with the array-stuff. For me 3 seconds for just 1000 operations seems like there must be any additional Debug-Options enabled. So, according to @nschum, try to make a release build.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var foo:String[] = ["A","b","c"];

    func viewDidLoadWithout() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func viewDidLoadWith() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for (var i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
            foo += "bar";
        }
    }
}

var time: Int = Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate())
var cntrl = ViewController()
cntrl.viewDidLoadWithout()
time -= Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate())
time *= (-1) // 7secs

time = Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate())
cntrl = ViewController()
cntrl.viewDidLoadWith()
time -= Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate())
time *= (-1) // 10secs
```

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here.

In the former case you have a property of an objc class and the value is in fact an NSString. At each update of the property not only you have a dynamic dispatch call to update the property, but also another to compute the new string. Each time there is a check for the possibility that there's some Objective C observer that needs notifying. And each intermediate value is allocated on the heap. All the strings also gets eventually released and deallocated.

In the latter case it's a stack value of type String (not an NSString). And there's no one that can see it but this code. The compiler could in fact even pre-compute the size of the final result and allocate it just once, then just do a quick loop to fill it.

Not saying this is exactly what happens. I'm guessing. But the two things are certainly different.

34 seconds however is **a lot**. There must be something else too.

Comment: Something seems off with this... I'm almost thinking that it is generating the 'snapshots' it uses for timelines in playground in the former case for some reason. This code is not even running in playground though. Definitely puzzling